# C# copying folders from server

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Application2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Uses the text entered by user
            //searchAndCopy(txtbox1.Text);

            //Uses file for copy process
            searchAllLines(@"D:\Icyer\liste2.txt");
        }

        private void searchAllLines(string filename)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
            {
                searchAndCopy(line);
            }
        }

        private void searchAndCopy(string textToSearch)
        {
//            MessageBox.Show("|" + textToSearch + "|");
            string srcfolder = @"X:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx";
            DirectoryInfo Ordner = new DirectoryInfo(srcfolder);
            FileInfo[] Pfad = Ordner.GetFiles("*" + textToSearch + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var item in Pfad)
            {
                string destinationDirectory = @"D:\xxxx\Copy\";
                //Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);
                string[] substrings = item.FullName.Split('\\');
                string folder = substrings[srcfolder.Split('\\').Length - 1];

                if(folder == textToSearch) {
                    DirectoryCopy(srcfolder + folder, destinationDirectory + folder, true);
                }
                //File.Copy(item.FullName, item.Name);

            }
        }

        private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                    "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " + sourceDirName);
            }

            // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }


            // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                try
                {
                    // Copy the file.
                    file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
                }
                catch { };
            }

            // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
            if (copySubDirs)
            {

                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    // Create the subdirectory.
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

                    // Copy the subdirectories.
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                }
                //MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly fine when I try to copy from "D: to D:", when I try to change the code from

```
string srcfolder = @"D:\xxxx\xxxx\";
```

to

```
string srcfolder = @"X:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx";
```

The application freezes the second I press on the button. Can someone tell me if it has to do because I'm trying to copy files from a server or is there an error in the code somewhere. Access to the server is granted and I have rights to copy files. Destination should stay on "D:". "X:" to "X:" doesnt work either, Application freezes the second the button is pressed.

Comment: Did you try to debug where the freeze does occure? Could it be that you just get very much files and the line 'FileInfo[] Pfad = Ordner.GetFiles("*" + textToSearch + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);' does take that long? - In general it is recommended to off-load intensive operations from the GUI thread to another thread that the GUI does not get stale.

Comment: you are doing the copying on the UI thread.. so it will hang while it works you need to offload it

Comment: I just tried debugging, at the line FileInfo[] Pfad = Ordner.GetFiles("*" + textToSearch + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); it gets stuck, up until that point it goes smooth, after that it stops working. But is there an explenation why it works fine from "D:" to "D:" and stops working when accessing the server "X:". As soon as I pass the line to "foreach (var item in Pfad) it stops (to make it more clear)

Comment: Ok so what I did was I shortened the list for files it had so search and copy, after a minute the application responds again BUT it did not copy the files that were in the list.txt and how would I go about offloading, never done that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comments indicate there are to many files in the directory and you are retrieving all and then iterating them again in your sub function. A local disk is always much faster than a network location - also perhaps  you just have some test data in your local disk and not the whole tree mirrored.

In general you should offload your processing into a separate thread - this way you can pass back 'status information' to your gui thread and display them (the application will not stale anymore).

With this line:

```
 FileInfo[] Pfad = Ordner.GetFiles("*" + textToSearch + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

you retrieve all files which match your textSearch string in all sub directories. Depending on the number of files and directories this can take a very long time.

Perhaps it would be better to iterate each directory recursive checking the content if something does need to get copied?

About offloading to another thread you can take a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/make_it_better/2017/05/15/updating-windows-form-ui-elements-from-another-thread/)

Comment: Can you give me a sample code for recursive checking?

Comment: Check out this [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree) : )

Comment: I get the idea behind it but with the lack of my skills I honstely dont know how I would have to change my code in order to achieve that. It doesnt have to be copy, it can be move too.

Comment: @ZeouLs never think of 'lack of skills' - think of it as 'learning something new'. Eg. start by creating the recursive copy function step by step. Do not think of the whole think, divide the work to be done into small steps and you will surely achieve it : ) At the beginning it is much reading/learning and debugging understanding the whole program flow

Comment: the thing is, I need to read the folder names from a list.txt and move/copy them to somehwere else but looking at the msdn page 1. they do it with a console app and 2. they dont use a list.txt to get the folder names but use a single file to move. My brain is about to explode

Comment: There is no difference between a windows forms or a console application beside the GUI : ) The same methods will run in both projects without any difference. There is also no difference for your handling - you just need to call your new method from  searchAndCopy(line);

Comment: I have written a new code this time trying System.IO.File.Move but I'm not certain what else I'm missing since I'm getting an error that the file couldnt be found. Is it because I'm searching not for files but folders?https://pastebin.com/GXsXVHF7

Comment: Yes, you need to search for files in each folder - but only in this directory not in all directories : )

Comment: let me give you an idea what I'm trying to do. I have 200Gb of files. The files start with the same name as the folder they are in. I need the folders including those files and move them somwhere else. So I dont need only the files, but whole folder where each file is located. For that I have a list.txt containing the foldernames. I need to import the list, search for the foldername and move or copy them somewhere else. I already have the first method I posted but as I said that one gets stuck and would take ages so I'm trying to make it work with System.IO.File.Move._.

Comment: There will be no difference using File.Move or File.Copy in terms of speed (move is just copy with final delete). If you get all files at once - you will need to wait until your operating system is finished. If you parse each directory and check the files inside this directory you could handle the copy directly or build the list and finally copy them. There is realy no difference, just that directory by directory will not stale for a long amount to get all files.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you correct, it wouldnt make any difference if I use copy or move but it would perform better if I change the way i search through the directory?

Comment: It would also take the same time in general, but as written before (if you are running the operation in a different file) you can give status updates - you can break the operation and you could perform the copy directly for each file

Comment: alright, thx mate if it doesnt make any difference in time, I guess I'll just run it as it is, I can let it run over the weekend and so on